# Как организовать клиент-серверную работу скриптов PHP и JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, клиент-сервер

- Есть PHP скрипт, который посылает запрос в API платежной системы и получает переменную $token.
- Есть JS скрипт, который должен открыть окно платежной системы используя переменную $token, полученную в PHP скрипте.

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на сайте, отрабатывал сначала первый скрипт на PHP, затем переменная $token передавалась в JS скрипт, затем отрабатывал второй скрипт на JS.

Как лучше организовать эту схему? Желательно на примере кода.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.GET( 
  [ТУТ ССЫЛКА НА ВАШ PHP СКРИПТ], 
  function(data)
  {
    [тут ваш скрипт который выполняется после PHP скрипта]
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Все просто при запросе пользователя у вас всегда будет сперва отрабатывать скрипт php
 на сервере который запрашивает юзер, там вы посылаете запрос в API платежной системы и формируете html документ, обычно делают проверку что токен получен тогда формируют объект js и делаю что нужно.
Пример:

```
<?if(!empty($sToken)):?>
   <script>
      var toket = '<?=$sToken;?>';
   </script>
<?endif;?>
```

Ну и дальше использовать переменную прямо в js скрипте
Так же можно передать допустим переменную php в создание объекта js и там ее обработать.

Надеюсь мой ответ помог вам.

Comment: А к кнопке мне привязывать скрипт PHP? А как потом запустить скрипт JS?

Comment: В кнопке у вас ссылка на скрипт php обработки, а js выполняется автоматически при загрузке страницы.

Comment: А мне надо чтобы JS скрипт выполнялся только при нажатии на кнопку и после PHP скрипта

Comment: Ну или можно по нажатию на кнопку отправлять ajax на php обработчик получать токен и далее выполнять обработку на стороне js